# Password validation fails using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I cannot validate the password field properly using Angular.js.Let me to explain my code first.

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.pass.$touched && billdata.pass.$invalid }">
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="pass" id="deptpass" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*_.*/" ng-keypress="clearField('deptpass');" >
 </div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.pass.$error" ng-if="billdata.pass.$touched">
<p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your password should be 8.</p>
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the special character like at least one number,upper case,lower case letter,_,@,#,&,%</p>
</div>
```

Here i am getting the message upto underscore(_).If user is typing `@,#,$,&,%` like character which should also taken by the field, it can not validate.Please help me.

Comment: So, you're basically asking us to debug that regex: `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*_.*/`

Comment: Ok,Where i will add these missing charcters.

Comment: Looks like you _require_ a underscore in the password...?

Comment: Yes,But i need also  `@,#,$,%,&` like  character with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong here then you require ng-pattern for password which contains at least one number,upper case,lower case letter,_,@,#,&,% with minimum length of 8.

Please use below ng-pattern:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[_!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/
```

This will only allow if string contains at least one number, upper case, lower case letter, _, @, #, &, % with minimum length 8.